# jQuery animate on scroll backgroundColor not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/owkqmtcc/5/

What I'm trying to accomplish: When I scroll anywhere in the div, the background color of the div "content" will change.  When the scroll rests at top of the div, it reverts back to its original color.  When I added height instead of background color, it works fine, but not sure why background color ain't working:

```js
$(function(){
var content = $(".content");

$(".box").scroll(function(event){
var positionofscroll = $(".content").scrollTop();

if(positionofscroll == 0){
content.stop().animate({
backgroundColor:"rgba(105, 63, 63, 0.69)"
},500);
}else {
content.stop().animate({
  backgroundColor:"red"
},500);

}
}); //scroll


});
```

```css
.box{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background:gray;
  overflow:auto;
}

.content{
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:1000px;
  background:red;
  font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Shadow Box when user scrolls -->

<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    I'm content
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including `jQuery UI` , as `.animate()` does not animate color without modifications or a color plugin; see [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> **Animation Properties and Values**
>
> All animated properties should be animated to a *single numeric
>   value*, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric
>   cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example,
>   `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated but `background-color`
>   cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used).

also adjusting selector at `positionofscroll` to  `$(this).scrollTop()`; changing comparison operator to `>` at `if`

```js
$(function() {
  var content = $(".content");

  $(".box").scroll(function(event) {
    var positionofscroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(positionofscroll);
    if (positionofscroll > 0) {
      content.stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgba(105, 63, 63, 0.69)"
      }, 500);
    } else {
      content.stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "red"
      }, 500);

    }
  }); //scroll


});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: gray;
  overflow: auto;
}
.content {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--Shadow Box when user scrolls -->

<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    I'm content
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var content = $(".content");

$(".box").scroll(function(event)
{
  var positionofscroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (positionofscroll > 0)
  {
    $(".content").css('background-color','rgba(105, 63, 63, 0.69)');
  }
  else 
  {
    $(".content").attr('style','');
  }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4fc6pook/

If you want to animate the change of the background color, add some css to .content:

```
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
```

or something similar.
Hope this helps!